# Word for caring about the appearance of a matter but not its spirit

Tags: single-word-requests

### **"To care all about the appearance of a matter or a law, without paying attention to its meaning/spirit and essence"**

Actually, I look for a suitable word for to express such meaning, and place it in this text:

---

The Pharisee Jews were so/very/too ................ . That is to say, they were paying attention to the appearance of religious orders, but they didn't care about the spirit of those orders at all. Jesus told them: "You argue about the uncleanness of a dish with one another, but you do not argue about what is earned through usury or a forbidden and unclean way, that you eat in the same dish?! You're okay with usury, but you judge on trivial matters, such as the egg that a chicken laid on Saturday (Jewish holiday)?!"

The words I have found so far are:

- Formalistic

and

- Superficial observer

Also im not sure about to choose among these:

**1. Appearance of religious orders**

**or**

**2. Outward of religious orders**

---

Please leave me any kind of improvements and changes you think works within the whole text.

Comment: The word usually used is 'legalistic'.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'll note a few idioms in case they're of interest to you: The Pharisee Jews *couldn't see the forest for the trees*. The Pharisee Jews were *down in the weeds*. Both terms connote a failure to see the big picture. I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: Is this not the same Question as https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/534073/appearance-or-outward?

Answer (score 3):

The word usually used, at least in Christian theology, is **legalistic**.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/legalistic) gives a fitting definition of the noun (the noun and adjective have closely corresponding meanings):

> *legalism* noun
>
> - strict adherence, or the principle of strict adherence, to law or prescription, especially to the letter rather than the spirit.

................

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/legalistic) is more incisive in its definition, from a Christian perspective:

> *legalistic* adjective
>
> - 1 Adhering excessively to law or formula.
>
>   - ‘our conciliation process avoids an overly legalistic approach’
>   - ‘narrow legalistic definitions’
> - 1.1 [Theology] Concerning adherence to moral law rather than to personal religious faith....

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to do this, but I like your answer.

Comment: It's great when you're happy with what you're cut-and-pasting.