# Industry sources meaning

Tags: meaning, translation

### I don't really understand the meaning of the term: **"Industry sources"** in this text. please aware me.

"Details of the agreement have yet to be made public, but **industry sources** have said Noble and Delek will be allowed to keep control of Leviathan, the world's largest offshore gas discovery of the past decade. "

Comment: As @Kevin has indicated in his answer, *outward* makes no sense here. Please edit your question accordingly. I would edit it myself, but only you know your intent.

Comment: If you're trying to Ask about the relationship of "outward" and "appearance" can you make that more clear?

If that's what you mean, "appearance" and "outward appearance" are virtually interchangeable except for a difference in emphasis.

Either way, "outward" by itself has so little place here it seems merely bizarre.

Comment: Is this not the same Question as https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/534042/word-for-caring-about-the-appearance-of-a-matter-but-not-its-spirit?

Answer (score 2):

In response to *Your idea?*, how about **letter**, as in **the letter of the law**? From M-W:

> **[the letter of the law](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/letter%20of%20the%20law)**: exactly what the law says

Your example:

> The Pharisee Jews were extremely legalistic. That is to say, they were paying attention to *the **letter** of the religious orders* (i.e., **the letter of the law**) … rather than ...

People often contrast **the *letter* of the law** (e.g., of religious orders) to **the *spirit* of the law** (e.g., of religious orders).

Comment: I'm guessing that the intent is to refer to appearance vs actual practice or perhaps spirit.

Comment: @HotLicks We're both guessing ...

Answer (score 0):

"Outward" by itself makes no sense here.

> they were paying attention to the appearance of religious order

Sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: Perhaps the OP intended *outward appearance* rather than *outward* alone? I'll comment on the question.